# Retrieving a class

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to get a class instead of a layout. This is the code.
I want to retrieve a class because it has functionality. Instead of a layout just designs

```
// layouts of all welcome sliders
        // add few more layouts if you want
        layouts = new int[]{
                R.layout.welcome_slide1,
                R.layout.welcome_slide2,
                R.layout.welcome_slide3,
              //  R.layout.welcome_slide4};
```

Comment: No. `MainActivity.this.getClass().getSimpleName()` is a String, not a Resource ID.

Comment: Please edit your question again to clarify **why** you need this and **what** you are trying to do with this data as a [mcve]

Comment: basically i want a class because it has the functionality.

Comment: What functionality?? Please show a [mcve] of **how** this data is useful (assuming you can get it)

Answer (score 0):

All Java objects have a `getClass()` method.

That returns a `Class` object.

I don't know what you are showing with a `int[]`, but you can use a `Class[]` or `Activity[]`